# Heroku Not Recognizing Rmagick Font

Tags: heroku, fonts, imagemagick, rmagick

My Heroku app doesn't appear to want to recognize ANY kind of rmagick font family.  In the following situation I would expect the font to be Times New Roman, but it is instead some system default.  I've tried changing to Helvetica, and it's the same result - generic looking system font of some sort.

```
canvas = Magick::Image.read("caption:#{@statement.text}"){
            self.size = "300x300"
            self.colorspace = RGBColorspace
            self.background_color = 'white'
            self.font = "TimesNewRoman"
            # self.font = "Helvetica"
            self.gravity = CenterGravity
            self.pointsize = 26
        }.first
```

I've run `identify -list font` and observed that both TimesNewRoman and Helvetica are recognized by the system, but my image refuses to use them.

Bonus context:  this is for the preview image in an og:image meta tag for display in Messages/Facebook Messager/etc.  If I futz with the font family and display the image directly onto an html page there's no problem and it uses the appropriate font.

Comment: You may have to specify fonts by path to the font file rather than the name. You would need fontconfig installed and would have to edit your type.xml file to add font names. Have you checked the font name variations with spaces such as Times New Roman? If Helvetica does not work are you sure you have its font file installed?

Comment: @fmw42 Interesting, I'll give that a shot tomorrow morning.  I'd tried setting an ENV variable with my staging URL followed by /assets/[name] but no dice.  Is that type.xml something that would get pushed to staging?  As for being sure if I have Helvetica installed, I assume that if it shows up in `identify -list font` then it's installed?  Because it IS there.

Comment: It won't show up with `identify -list font` unless it is added to the type.xml file. You have to find where it is located on your system. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php. On my IM 6.9.9.23 version, it is at /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/type.xml. See Anthony Thyssen script, http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/imagick_type_gen, to automatically add all compatible fonts. Otherwise, just use the path to the font file

Comment: That's what I'm saying though - Helvetica (and TimesNewRoman) ARE showing up in my staging server's `identify -list font`, which is why I'm so confused.  I'll play around with fontconfig and see if that gets me anywhere.

Comment: Try just using the path to your font file itself. That should work. See if path2/Helvetica.ttf works, assuming it is a .ttf font.

Comment: Do you know where fonts are installed on Heroku?  It's possible that it's NOT actually installed, and that `identify -list font` is just reporting it as an option even though there's nothing there.  Heroku doesn't have a `/Library/Fonts` like I'd use locally, so not sure where else it'd be.

Comment: Wowwwwwwwwww...apparently it's as easy as adding a `.fonts` folder to the root of your Heroku app and then moving your font into there - once you do that you can just reference the font directly when setting it onto ImageMagick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comment in the chain above:

Wowwwwwwwwww...apparently it's as easy as adding a `.fonts` folder to the root of your Heroku app and then moving your font into there - once you do that you can just reference the font directly when setting it onto ImageMagick...

So...yeah.

```
.fonts
| - "SF-Pro-Text-Light.otf
| - "SF-Pro-Text-Regular.otf
```

and

```
canvas = Magick::Image.read("caption:#{@statement.text}"){
        self.size = "300x300"
        self.colorspace = RGBColorspace
        self.background_color = 'white'
        self.font = "SF-Pro-Text-Light"
        self.gravity = CenterGravity
        self.pointsize = 26
    }.first
```